# Python upgraded installing other library, previous version paths are there, but not executable

Tags: path, ide, dependencies, python-3.6

Series of problems!

Should probably have made env first - which now I am doing,,but cannot overturn what is done- and installed the package within it, so as not to affect dependencies of others. But this is done already.

Now the installed module is imported finely, but IDE does not recognize the interpreter anymore. I was using python 3.5 previously. Now with `graph-tool` library from the awesome `http://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier` channel,, (works for OS X perfectly)

Following either makes sense, or.. was resolved,

1. I cannot use all the libraries installed on the previous python version
2. I cannot set `Interpreter` setting on IDE `preferences` tab, (maybe my lack of knowledge)
3. `whereis python`, `which python` on terminal & `sys.executable` on python all point to what they did before the upgraded python was executed on the terminal. So this could be why I am not sure where to designate for path on IDEs

but why can I not execute python 3.5 like I can with 2.7? Is it because conda-installed 3.5 was upgraded to 3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just located alias and designated, IDE recognized it.

Probably have to remove all previous versions of python though.

Or use them separately for different working environments (not very meaningful using one Mac)